# Microsoft Outlook: "To protect your privacy, some pictures in this message were not downloaded."

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, privacy

Using Microsoft Outlook, nearly all of the email messages I receive have the warning:

[image: To protect your privacy, some pictures in this message were not downloaded.]

> To protect your privacy, some pictures in this message were not downloaded.
>
> Download pictures

How can I force Outlook to display these images automatically in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Microsoft Outlook for Mac, the setting is located here:

Preferences > Email > Reading > Security

> Automatically download pictures from the Internet:
>
> - In all messages
> - In messages from my contacts
> - Never

So, either add your image-senders to your contacts, or select "In all messages".

Comment: Seems that you have already found your answer. Thanks for your sharing.